# Clear InfoPath form field after hitting submit?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, submit

Can anyone tell me how I would clear a from field after the submit button has been clicked? I have a field that I'm using as a password field to unhide fields if the password is entered bit I don't want the password data to stay in as form data. The name of the password field is txt_locker. I would assume ID do it through a rule on txt_locker but not sure how to tell it that the submit button has been clicked.

I'm using SharePoint 2010 with InfoPath 2010. I have no access to SharePoint designer and am on a networked SharePoint with no access to user account listings so this is a workaround to keep certain users out of certain fields.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add rule to the Save Button as below to clear password field

[image]

[Ref](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7c441bdb-37d1-4ff8-a670-45f1ff9de0c6/how-to-clear-the-text-from-text-box-of-infopath-form-in-infopath-form-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointcustomization)